# O que tem de errado nesse código?

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis, get, delete

tudo bem?

Sou iniciante no PHP e estou "ilhado" num código simples, no qual já vi inúmeras respostas aqui no fórum, e fiz exatamente igual como está nas respostas (até o CTRL+C CTRL+V) e não funciona.

É o seguinte:

Preciso capturar o conteúdo de uma variável (pelo $_GET[]) e excluir esse conteúdo do banco de dados.

A captura está perfeita. Realmente ele reconhece o conteúdo, armazena na variável e tals... (fiz vários testes e deram certos).
Más o que tá me dando um nó na cabeça, é que não consegue excluir o registro do bd.

O Código é esse:

```
    <?php 

require_once "dbconfigurator.php";

$id = $_GET['emaillead'];

if(isset($id)) {

    $apaga = "DELETE FROM leads WHERE codlead=" . $id;

    $apagando = mysqli_query($apaga) or die ('Erro ao Apagar Email');

    $fechando = mysqli_close($conexaobd);

    echo "<h1>Sentiremos sua falta!</h1><br><h3>O email " . $id . " foi excluido de nosso banco de dados!</h3>";
    } else {
        echo "Email não encontrado!";
        }



?>
```

Preciso saber onde está o erro, pois ele encontra o conteúdo da variável, más não deleta do banco. O arquivo dbconfigurator.php está correto, pois o mesmo é utilizado no arquivo captura.php e o mesmo faz a inserção no banco de dados perfeitamente.

Fico no aguardo!!

Comment: Copiou errado, o primeiro argumento de `mysqli_query()` sempre é a conexão. Evite sql injection.

Comment: Como sou novo no PHP não entendi direito. Então deixa eu entender: dentro do mysqli_query() não devo por a variável $apaga e sim a conexão. Mas como eu coloco a conexão e que conexão é essa? Do bando de dados (a mesma q está no require_once). Favor me explicar com mais detalhes se puder.

Comment: No arquivo captura.php, tem a linha: $gravando = mysql_query("INSERT INTO leads(nomelead, emaillead) VALUES ('$nome', '$email')"); que funciona perfeitamente. Então coloquei a mesma linha apenas alterando para DELETE FROM leads WHERE emaillead=$id, e mesmo assim, não faz o "prometido"... Também lá no require_once, coloquei dentro de uma variável e essa variável, coloquei no mysql_query() e tbm nada.

Comment: Todas as funções que tem o prefixo `mysql_` foram removidas das versões mais nova o php7, existe outra API para conectar no banco de dados suas funções tem o prefixo `mysqli_ `(note que tem um **i** no final de Improved) e na maioria delas o primeiro argumento é a conexão, veja um exemplo simples de como usar elas [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/mysqli/info). Se tiver mais alguma dúvida coloque uma arroba antes do nome do usuário, assim vc notifica ele, ex @rray.

Comment: Amigo, primeiramente agradeço pelo esforço que estas desprendendo para esse projeto meu... más infelizmente ainda não consegui... olha só.. a versão do meu servidor é o PHP 5.6. Procurei por vários blogs e fóruns e vi q as sintaxes estão corretas. O meu código é esse:

 $apaga = "delete from leads where emaillead=$id";

 $apagando = mysql_query($apaga,$conexaobd) or die (mysql_error());
 
 $fechando = mysql_close($conexaobd);

Agora lhe pergunto. Se a sintaxe está correta, onde mais poderá ter erro?

Comment: Manda ai o código;

Comment: Esse é o erro: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@molurefri.com.br' at line 1

Comment: `codlead` é um `varchar`? ele diz q sua consulta tem um erro de sintaxe. Se for adicione aspas simples nesse valor/variável.

Comment: codlead é um int(11) A.I.

Comment: Então o problema é `$_GET['emaillead']` deveria ser um número e está vindo um email. Se esse dado vem por um link, ele está passando errado.

Comment: más o campo emaillead e nomelead, são varchar, apenas o codlead é inteiro. Minha intenção é resgatar o endereço do email do cliente que vem pela url pela variavel emaillead.

Comment: vc deveria passar pela url o `codlead`, se for passar o email na consulta faça: `$apaga = "DELETE FROM leads WHERE codlead= '$id'";` Na consulta sql qualquer valor/variável deve estar entre aspas simples.

Comment: Tenho duas coisas pra falar... a primeira.. aquele erro "maldito" saiu... show de bola... passa pelo IF e tals e chega até o final...

Comment: só que.... não apaga no banco de dados... fui lá no phpmyadmin e o registro ainda está lá...

Comment: então ele tá só enganando os usuários... o que mais pode estar errado?

Comment: UUAAALLLLLLLL agora que te entendi!!! DEU CERTO! Mudei o codlead para emaillead e funcionou perfeitamenteeeee

Comment: muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: Legal que conseguiu resolver :)